# Dynamically adding an Android layout using for loop

Tags: android, android-layout, for-loop, view, android-relativelayout

Ok so this is a method I use to draw a list of individual recipe steps using RelativeLayouts in a parent LinearLayout. The RelativeLayouts contain a TextView beside an Icon, which both should change with each i++. I can't find anything wrong with it, there are no errors or exceptions, the results just don't show.

Is this the best way to do this? Is there a better way? Should I just learn how to use a ListView? Is it easier? Any help is appreciated.

```
    stepsList.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i=0; i==arrayLength; i++) {
        RelativeLayout stepsBlock = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
        ImageView recipeIcon = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        TextView recipeText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams blockParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iconParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        blockParams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 0);
        if (i > 0) {
            stepsBlock.setLayoutParams(blockParams);
        }
        stepsBlock.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        stepsBlock.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b69878"));

        iconParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        iconParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        iconParams.setMargins(0, 0, 6, 0);
        recipeIcon.setBackgroundResource((com.package.app.R.drawable.iconwhite)+(i));
        recipeIcon.setLayoutParams(iconParams);
        recipeIcon.setId(1);

        textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, recipeIcon.getId());
        recipeText.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
        recipeText.setText(recipeTinDough[i]);
        recipeText.setTextSize(12);
        recipeText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        recipeText.setLayoutParams(textParams);
        recipeText.setId(2);

        stepsList.addView(stepsBlock);
        stepsBlock.addView(recipeIcon);
        stepsBlock.addView(recipeText);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, try changing the WRAP_CONTENT of blockParams to MATCH_PARENT

Comment: blockParams is the RelativeLayout 'block' which contains the information, it's supposed to take up the entire width of the LinearLayout, but i'll try anything, thanks.

Comment: No that did not work, any other suggestions?

Comment: show us how you inflated `stepsList`

Comment: stepsList is the id of the LinearLayout to add the individual RelativeLayout blocks too. I haven't inflated anything

Comment: how come `stepsList.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);` worked? if it's an id it should not compile at all.

Comment: No I mean stepsList is the Integer of the findViewById(linearlayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to implement this whole thing with a ListView for the following reason:

1. Memory efficient
2. Views get recycled
3. refreshing data would be simpler
4. Easier to **manage** once you understand how it works

But in case if you don't want to use ListView:

1. use layouts, manually creating and setting values for views makes it hard to maintain in the future
2. Second, `setPadding` and `setMargins` uses pixels, not dip, setting a 3 pixel padding seems odd(same goes for margins)
3. `recipeIcon.setBackgroundResource((com.package.app.R.drawable.iconwhite)+(i));` is wrong, you are adding the resource id with 1, android would most likely not be able to find the resource you're looking for.

You might have to make `stepsList` match parent as well. I can't really tell with this much of code.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my only option is to use a ListView, but can you place it multiple times to the length of an array using a for loop inside a LinearLayout parent?

Comment: You mean place multiple ListViews in a LinearLayout? sure, there is nothing that constrains you from nesting Views

Comment: Thanks Tom, got a ListView working now, tricky, but very nice. Cheers